# How to add a spinner icon to the the first td if 9th td text is process when using datables.js in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using Bootstrap 3, `datables.js` and `font-awesome` in my MVC project i want to add a spinner icon from font awesome to the first `td` of the row which has a data in process the code that i have written will explain it in detail and the code that i have tried so far is as follows:

the image of what i get is as follows:

http://s18.postimg.org/o9umczux5/spin.png

and what I want is in my first td i.e column srno I want to add a spinner when column status text is Process.

the below is my javascript for table using `datables.js`:-

```js
//-----------FOR Recharge Grid Start-----------------//

$(function recharge() {
  var c = $("#BindRechargeexample").DataTable({
    "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
      if (aData[9] == 'Process') {
        $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner  fa-spin"></i>')
        $(nRow).addClass('warning')
      } else if (aData[9] == 'Deleted') {
        $(nRow).addClass('danger')
      } else if (aData[9] == "Complited") {
        if (aData[11] != "0" && aData[11] != "00") {
          $(nRow).css("color", "red")
        } else {
          $(nRow).css("color", "black")
        }
      }
    },
    "lengthMenu": [
      [10, 50, 100, -1],
      [10, 50, 100, "All"]
    ],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "searchable": false,
      "orderable": false,
      "targets": 0
    }, {
      "targets": [11],
      "visible": false,
      "searchable": false
    }],
    "order": [
      [8, 'desc']
    ],
  });
  c.on('order.dt search.dt', function() {
    c.column(0, {
      search: 'applied',
      order: 'applied'
    }).nodes().each(function(cell, i) {
      cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
    });
  }).draw();
});
//-----------FOR Recharge Grid END-----------------//
```

and i am also refreshing the datable every 10 sec to check wether the data is in process or not and the code for that is as below:-

```js
//------For Refreshing Of Recharge Grid--------//
//-------Recharge Page-----WEBGRID--------------//
$(function loadgrid() {
  var path = window.location.href;
  if (path == 'http://localhost:55261/Retailer/Recharge') {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/Retailer/CheckRechargeGrid',
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        test: 'json'
      }),
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.status == true) {
          $.get('/Retailer/_BindRecharge', function(result) {
            $('#testing').html(result);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.grid; i++) {
              toastr.warning('The Given Recharge is in Process!!', 'Recharge In Process!!!', toastr.options.positionClass = "toast-bottom-left");
            }
          });
          setTimeout(loadgrid, 10000);
        } else {
          $.get('/Retailer/_BindRecharge', function(result) {
            $('#testing').html(result);
          });
          if (data.grids > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= data.grid; i++) {
              toastr.success('Recharge Completed!!', 'Recharge Process Completed!!!', toastr.options.positionClass = "toast-bottom-left");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
//------For Refreshing Of Recharge Grid--------//
//-------Recharge Page-----WEBGRID--------------//
```

and the view is over here :-

```html
@model List<NomzyMVC.Models.BindRechargeModel>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-body">
                <div id="loadgrid">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        if (Model != null)
                        {
                            var Grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: false, canSort: false);
                        @Grid.GetHtml(
                       tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover",
                       htmlAttributes: new { id = "BindRechargeexample" },
                        columns:
                           Grid.Columns(
                           Grid.Column(columnName: "Agenttransno", header: "Sr No"),
                           Grid.Column(columnName: "Agenttransno", header: "AgenttransNo"),
                           Grid.Column(columnName: "Company", header: "Company"),
                           Grid.Column(columnName: "ProductCode", header: "Product"),
                           Grid.Column(columnName: "Account", header: "Account"),
                           Grid.Column(columnName: "Amount", header: "Amount", style: "alignright"),
                           Grid.Column(columnName: "Discount", header: "Discount", style: "alignright"),
                           Grid.Column(columnName: "ClosingBal", header: "ClosingBal", style: "alignright"),
                           Grid.Column(columnName: "DT", header: "DT"),
                           Grid.Column(columnName: "Status", header: "Status"),
                           Grid.Column(columnName: "Result", header: "Result"),
                           Grid.Column(columnName: "ResultCode", header: "ResultCode"))
                          );
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

and the code for controller is as follows:

This is for binding the data into the grid:

```
public PartialViewResult _BindRecharge()
        {
            try
            {
                var grid = (from c in NMSDC.vw_Web_Recharge_Status
                            where c.DT >= System.DateTime.Now.Date && c.DT <= System.DateTime.Now && c.UserID == Session["UserID"].ToString() orderby c.DT descending
                            select new BindRechargeModel
                            {
                                Agenttransno = c.agenttransno.ToString(),
                                Company = c.Company,
                                Account = c.account,
                                Amount = c.value,
                                ProductCode = c.productcode,
                                Discount = (decimal)c.RCommission,
                                ClosingBal = (decimal)c.RLastBalance,
                                Status = c.Status,
                                DT = c.DT,
                                Result = c.NomadicDescription,
                                ResultCode=c.ResultCode
                            }).ToList().Take(10);
                return PartialView(grid.ToList());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                redirect();
            }
            return PartialView();
        }
```

And the the code for refresh is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CheckRechargeGrid()
    {
        bool status;
        var grids = (from c in NMSDC.vw_Web_Recharge_Status
                     where c.DT >= System.DateTime.Now.Date && c.DT <= System.DateTime.Now && c.UserID == Session["UserID"].ToString()
                     select new BindRechargeModel
                     {
                         Agenttransno = c.agenttransno.ToString(),
                         Company = c.Company,
                         Account = c.account,
                         Amount = c.value,
                         ProductCode = c.productcode,
                         Discount = (decimal)c.RCommission,
                         ClosingBal = (decimal)c.RLastBalance,
                         Status = c.Status,
                         DT = c.DT,
                         Result = c.NomadicDescription
                     }).ToList();
        var grid = (from c in NMSDC.vw_Web_Recharge_Status
                    where c.DT >= System.DateTime.Now.Date && c.DT <= System.DateTime.Now && c.UserID == Session["UserID"].ToString() && c.ResultCode == null || c.ResultCode == ""
                    select new BindRechargeModel
                    {
                        ResultCode = c.ResultCode,
                        Status = c.Status
                    }).ToList();
        if (grid.ToList().Count > 0)
        {
            status = true;
        }
        else
        {
            status = false;
        }
        return Json(new { grid = grid.ToList().Count,grids=grids.ToList().Count, status = status }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var c = $("#BindRechargeexample").DataTable({
"oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": '<div><img src=spinner.gif" /></div>',
    },
});
```

use the above option in your `DataTable` function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to add a spinner. That's the easy part. The trick is getting it to show and hide at the right times. I'll assume you can get it to show on your own. In order to hide it once the table loads, there is a specific function in datatables.

You need to add something like this:

```
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
$('#loadingSpinner").hide();
 //do whatever you want to hide the spinner...this is just an example
}
```

This could go right after this in your code:

```
"order": [
      [8, 'desc']
    ],
```

Comment: I want to show a spinner on my first td when the data on my 9th td is Process as you can see in my code here i have change the color of that row in this code:

Comment: "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
      if (aData[9] == 'Process') {
        $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner  fa-spin"></i>')
        $(nRow).addClass('warning')
      } else if (aData[9] == 'Deleted') {
        $(nRow).addClass('danger')
      } else if (aData[9] == "Complited") {
        if (aData[11] != "0" && aData[11] != "00") {
          $(nRow).css("color", "red")
        } else {
          $(nRow).css("color", "black")
        }
      }
    },